# Package.json when deploying Meteor on Modulus

Tags: meteor, modulus

I'm trying to push an updated version of my Meteor app to Modulus after switching dev environment but I now get the following:

Client:

```
Unable to connect to any application instances.
```

Server:

```
Now using node v6.2.0
Found package.json: ./package.json
WARNING: Main file not specified in package.json.
WARNING: Looking for common main file names: index.js, app.js, server.js, main.js.
ERROR: No main or start script found. There is no application to run.
```

Before pushing this last update, the server log looked like below after successful startup but I'm not sure what the actual problem is. Any ideas?

Last functioning startup message on server:

```
Now using node v0.10.41
Found package.json: ./programs/server/package.json
Start script specified in package.json: node ../../main
Running command: npm start

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start /mnt/app/programs/server
> node ../../main

Now using node v0.10.41
Found package.json: ./programs/server/package.json
Start script specified in package.json: node ../../main
Running command: npm start
```

Comment: Facing the Same Issue ... Any Solution ?

Comment: After updating to Meteor 1.3 the Modulus runtime had gotten switched to NodeJS instead of Meteor for some reason. I corrected this and it was working again after I resolved a number of (unrelated) NPM issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record, it depends on your modulus-CLI version:

- With **modulus-CLI version <= 5.x**, you have to use a Modulus **Node.js** runtime. The `modulus deploy` command will demeteorize your Meteor project (essentially build it and modify a few parameters, including the `package.json` file, to specify the start script) and upload the resulting bundle to your Node instance.
- With **modulus-CLI version >= 6.0.0**, you have to use a Modulus **Meteor** runtime. The `modolus deploy` command will directly upload your Meteor project source code (except what is specified in `.modulusignore` file), and the magic will happen on the build server Modulus side.

Comment: Exactly. A warning from the CLI would have been lovely.